# Change a line in a file using php

Tags: php

mytext.txt

I have a file named as mytext.txt and it contain some data as shown below:

```
This is the file contain new data.

That have some error.

that need to fix.

dummy data

I am trying to fix

This is the file contain new data.

That have some error.

that need to fix.

dummy data
```

In this file I need to change the line "I am trying to fix" to "that is out of scope".
And write to mytext.txt.

Can any one help me to do this?

Comment: What are your errors?

Comment: As @KheshavSewnundun said, What problems have you gotten? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$reading = fopen('myfile', 'r');
$writing = fopen('myfile.tmp', 'w');

$replaced = false;

while (!feof($reading)) {
  $line = fgets($reading);
  if (stristr($line,'certain word')) {
    $line = "replacement line!\n";
    $replaced = true;
  }
  fputs($writing, $line);
}
fclose($reading); fclose($writing);
// might as well not overwrite the file if we didn't replace anything
if ($replaced) 
{
  rename('myfile.tmp', 'myfile');
} else {
  unlink('myfile.tmp');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file size is really this small this is the simplest way I can think of:

```
$text = file_get_contents('mytext.txt');
$text = str_replace('I am trying to fix', 'that is out of scope', $text);
file_put_contents('mytext.txt', $text);
```

Blam